# Javascript. Math.sqrt giving NaN to a positive number?

Tags: javascript

I currently have a script that takes numbers from a text area and does all sorts of calculations with them. I am having trouble with my standard deviation function because it will not output the value even though it's type is number, and it is positive (.56).

When I run this code

```
var variance = findVariance(array);
    variance = parseFloat(variance);
    alert(typeof variance);
```

the result is

> number

And the value is .56 (which I know because when I don't use parseFloat it returns .56 as a string). So I am baffled when I run this code

```
alert("variance " + variance);
alert("sd" + Math.sqrt(variance));
```

and both alerts return

> NaN

This is the code that creates the textarea,  calls the function processData( which gathers the input from myTextArea into an array and then calls the function findStandardDeviation) I can post the variance function as well if you'd like.

```
<textarea id="myTextArea" rows = "7" cols = "50"></textarea><br>

<button onclick="processData()">Done</button>

<p id = "sd"></p>

<script type = "text/javascript">

        var standard_deviation = 0;

        var sdOutput = document.getElementById('sd'); 

    function processData()
    {
        var arrayOfLines = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value.split('\n');


        findStandardDeviation(arrayOfLines);
    }
```

This is the most reducible form of my script I could manage:

```js
var mean = 0;
var median = 0;
var count = length;
var mode = 0;
var variance = 0;
var standard_deviation = 0;

var meanOutput = document.getElementById('mean');
var countOutput = document.getElementById('count');
var sumOutput = document.getElementById('sum');
var varianceOutput = document.getElementById('variance');
var sdOutput = document.getElementById('sd');

function processData() {
  var arrayOfLines = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value.split('\n');

  var sum = findSum(arrayOfLines);
  findMeanOutput(arrayOfLines, sum);
  findVariance(arrayOfLines);
  findStandardDeviation(arrayOfLines);
}

function findSum(array) {
  var count = array.length;
  var sum = 0;

  for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    sum += parseInt(array[a]);
  }

  countOutput.innerHTML = "Count: " + array.length;
  sumOutput.innerHTML = "Sum: " + JSON.stringify(sum);
  sum = parseInt(sum);
  return sum;
}

function findMean(array) //Used for finding mean and then returning it
{
  var sum = 0;

  for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    sum += parseFloat(array[a]);
  }

  mean = sum / array.length;
  return mean;
}

function findMeanOutput(array, sum) //finds mean and then establishes it as the mean for users input
{
  mean = sum / array.length;
  meanOutput.innerHTML = "Mean: " + mean;
}

function findVariance(array) {
  var mean = findMean(array);

  var variance = "Variance: " + findMean(array.map(function(num) {
    return Math.pow(num - mean, 2);
  })).toFixed(2);

  varianceOutput.innerHTML = "Variance: " + variance;
  return variance;
}

function findStandardDeviation(array) {
  var variance = findVariance(array);
  variance = parseFloat(variance);
  alert(typeof variance);
  alert("variance " + variance);
  alert("sd" + Math.sqrt(variance));
  sdOutput.innerHTML = "Standard Deviation: " + Math.sqrt(variance).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p> Please enter a series of numbers, each separated by a new line.<br>
    <p>
      <textarea id="myTextArea" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea><br>
      <button onclick="processData()">Done</button>
      <p id="mean"></p>
      <p id="count"></p>
      <p id="sum"></p>
      <p id="variance"></p>
      <p id="sd"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet in the question that reproduces the problem? You can do that in the edit menu using the `<>` button.

Comment: parseInt should return int and you expect 0.56

Comment: Why are you still using `parseInt` on `variance`? `variance = parseInt(variance); variance = parseFloat(variance);` converts `variance` to `NaN` in the first line, then parses `NaN` as a float, which obviously still will be `NaN`. I already said _“you shouldn’t use `parseInt`”_.

Comment: @Xufox, Idr why I was just trying different things... Ok, I removed it but parseInt is still NaN.

Answer (score 1):

`.56` is not an integer, so you shouldn’t use `parseInt`. `parseFloat` is the function you’re looking for. Or much simpler: `Number`.

Comment: @palaѕн Uhm… `parseInt(".56")` is `NaN`. That’s exactly the issue.

Comment: Yup seems like that is the issue, as `typeof parseInt(".56") === 'number'`

Comment: Ok, I replaced parseInt with parseFloat and still it gives NaN for both alerts, I will update my post accordingly...

Comment: @Parker Make sure to create an executable snippet as Nisarg Shah already commented. Post an [mcve]. This may include your `findVariance` function. `alert` is _not_ meant for debugging. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and use `console.log` instead.

Comment: @Xufox Ok, I have.

Answer (score 0):

Try For this:

**in your case .56 is float, so use parseFloat**

1. **parseInt** - convert string to integer number, if you will float to it then it will give 0,
2. **parseFloat** - return number to float,

Comment: In this case `parseInt(".56")` yields `NaN` because `parseInt` tries to build an integer from the string from left to right. In `0.56` it only sees `0` as part of the integer. In `.56` it doesn’t see the string starting with any digit, so it yields `NaN` after stopping at the `.`.

Comment: it always gives to zero

Comment: What? `parseInt(".56")` is `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

I was appending the string "Variance: " to the variance variable alongside the actual variance, which when converted to a float still resulted in a NaN. I solved it by swapping this:

```
variance = parseFloat(variance);
```

out with this:

```
variance = parseFloat(+variance.match(/[\d.]+/)[0]);
```